# Parsing LLVM IR from bitcode file

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to parse LLVM IR from a bit code file. I went through the following steps.

hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello world!" << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

dump.cpp

```
#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>
#include <llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h>

using namespace llvm;
int main()
{
  LLVMContext context;
  SMDiagnostic error;
  Module *m = parseIRFile("hello.bc", error, context).get();
  if(m)
  {
    m->dump();
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

**$ clang++ -O3 -emit-llvm hello.cpp -c -o hello.bc**

**$ clang++ -g -O3 dump.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs all` -o dump**

**$ ./dump**

***Assertion failed: (Val && "isa<> used on a null pointer"), function doit, file /Users/chamibuddhika/Builds/llvm/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h, line 106.
Abort trap: 6***

So I get the above error at the end. What may be causing this? I am on llvm-6.0 rc2.

Comment: `LLVMContext context` is uninitialized. See here: http://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreContext.html

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-createcompilerllvm1/ This is a nice tutorial resource which teaches the initialization of the LLVM basics. Scroll halfway through (Listing 6.) for the required code.

Comment: From the Kaleidoscope tutorial at [link](https://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html#full-code-listing) the current API way of initializing LLVMContext is to just declare it globally. That also seems to fail. I am using C++ API. First link given in comments seems to be for C API and the second link seems to be bit outdated.

Comment: My bad then.. the interface seems to have changed in more recent releases. Could you try this command line to create the hello.bc file: `clang++ -S -O3 -emit-llvm hello.cpp -o c:\llvmtest\hello.bc`. The -S switch would create LLVM-IR in the output file hello.bc instead of binary data. Not sure if that is what you are after, but I suspect it is what the function `parseIRFile` would expect

Comment: It seems to have made bit of a difference in that it now makes it to module->dump(). But it now seg faults within there. Looks like this API is fragile at the moment.

Comment: Can you update your question with the console output from dump()?